# react native with firebase storage getDownloadUrl() error in android

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm using react native in Android and I'm hoping to download files from Firebase Storage.

But I'm getting this error when I use firebase storage .getDownloadUrl() method
(NB: The database works just fine)

> Could not close WebSocket connection for id 0
>
> java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
>                                                                 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.checkOpen(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:247)
>                                                                 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.-wrap0(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java)
>                                                                 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:756)
>                                                                 at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:80)
>                                                                 at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
>                                                                 at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:221)
>                                                                 at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter.writeControlFrame(WebSocketWriter.java:151)
>                                                                 at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.ws.WebSocketWriter.writeClose(WebSocketWriter.java:112)
>                                                                 at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.close(RealWebSocket.java:135)
>                                                                 at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.close(WebSocketModule.java:186)
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:343)
>                                                                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry$ModuleDefinition.call(NativeModuleRegistry.java:187)
>                                                                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.call(NativeModuleRegistry.java:62)
>                                                                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeModulesReactCallback.call(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:432)
>                                                                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnableDeprecated.run(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
>                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:187)
>                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

version:
react-native: 0.25.1

I don't get this error in my IOS emulator

Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: Which version of Firebase Storage are you using?

Comment: I'm using firebase 3.3.0
Actually, I resolved this by creating a native component and using firebase library for android (not for javascript)..
But it'll be great if I can use the javascript library.. So that I don't need to create separate components for IOS and Android.. Thanks!